# Missing label using Easy Custom Labeling?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I’m using the Easy Custom Labeling plugin (with QGIS 1.8). I have one feature label which refused to show itself. It’s just not visible. When I look at the attributes table, the feature name appears in the same columns as the names of all the other features. I’ve tried moving nearby labels away from it--no difference. I’ve tried moving the feature (just to see what would happen)—nothing. If I turn on Labels in the corresponding feature layer, the label appears.

Where’s my label?

Comment: Are you labeling points, lines or polygons? This behavior has been related to invalid polygons before.

Comment: So far I've found it with two points.

Comment: Now I found it happening with a line. I don't see anything invalid about any of these.

Comment: Now I discovered the line label appearing when I changed views (panned over a ways). Each time I pan back & forth, the label appears or disappears.

Comment: Ok, now I see that when I pan over, it changes where labels are displayed for nearby features. So if I pan to where the label was disappearing; then move the other nearby labels to other locations, the missing label appears.

Comment: However I still have at least one point whose label will not appear no matter how I pan or move other nearby labels.

Answer (score 2):

You can show all labels, regardless whether they intersect, by checking the box "Show all labels" in the Engine settings of the desired label's Layer labeling settings. The Engine settings can be found on the end of the extended options tab.[image]

If the missing label is still not displayed, I would try to edit the Label layer manually by overwriting the field in the attribute table with some other string.